# mingw32-make pattern rules not working

Tags: makefile, mingw32

Recently I've worked with mingw32-make in order to setup a learning project.

The goals were to implement a simple makefile which would take source files from different folders, put all the resulting object files in the /build folder and the final executable in the /bin folder (please see the intended structure below).

```
+-- bin (for binaries)
+-- build (for .o files)
+-- include
+-- lib
+-- src
     +-- main (.c and .h files)
     +-- xml (.c and .h files)
```

This was the resulting makefile (which actually works):

```
# compiler identifier
CC=g++
# compiler options
CFLAGS=-c -Wall

SRC_DIR    := src
INC_DIR    := include
LIB_DIR    := lib
BUILD_DIR  := build
BIN_DIR    := bin

MODULES    := main xml
SRC_DIRS   := $(addprefix $(SRC_DIR)/,$(MODULES))
SRC_FILES  := $(foreach dir,$(SRC_DIRS),$(wildcard $(dir)/*.c))
OBJ_FILES  := $(patsubst $(SRC_DIR)/%,$(BUILD_DIR)/%,$(SRC_FILES:.c=.o))
OBJ_DIRS   := $(patsubst $(SRC_DIR)/%,$(BUILD_DIR)/%,$(SRC_DIRS))

.PHONY: all clean

all : clean main

main: $(OBJ_FILES)
    $(CC) $^ -o $(BIN_DIR)/$@

$(OBJ_FILES) : 
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(INC_MOD) $(INC) $(patsubst $(BUILD_DIR)/%, $(SRC_DIR)/%, $(patsubst %.o, %.c, $@)) -o $@

clean: $(OBJ_DIRS)

$(OBJ_DIRS):
    mkdir $@
    del $@\* /f /q

print-% : ; @echo $* = $($*)
```

Now, it works but I'm pretty sure that the following line is not 100% correct:

```
 $(OBJ_FILES) : 
        $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(INC_MOD) $(INC) $(patsubst $(BUILD_DIR)/%, $(SRC_DIR)/%, $(patsubst %.o, %.c, $@)) -o $@
```

This is basically a workaround for the fact that mingw32-make doesn't seem to support pattern rules like this:

```
%.o : %.c
        $(CC) -c $(CFLAGS) $(CPPFLAGS) $< -o $@
```

The main question is: Has anyone else had the same issue?
Could someone indicate a better implementation? Thank you.

Comment: I find it entirely incomprehensibly unlikely that `mingw32-make` doesn't support pattern rules. Why do you believe that to be the case? And yes, your makefile is wrong because it doesn't list any prerequisites for any objects so they will never rebuild once the files exist.

Comment: My statement about mingw32-make was wrong. The tool clearly supports pattern rules but I cannot make them work in my context.

Comment: I've tried to use the following pattern rule: `OBJS:= $(notdir $(OBJ_FILES))
main: $(OBJS)
 $(CC) $^ -o $(BIN_DIR)/$@
 
%.o: %.c
 $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(INC_MOD) $(INC) $*.c -o $*.o`

The results look like this:
mingw32-make print-OBJS
OBJS = main.o xmlcomposer.o xmlparser.o   <--- this is correct

mingw32-make all
mingw32-make: *** No rule to make target 'main.o', needed by 'main'.  Stop.

It's the same result also for: build/%.o or $(BUILD_DIR)/%.o. I guess something is missing here.

Comment: Found the problem: the prerequisites must match existing source files paths.

Comment: Yes, prerequisites must either exist or be buildable.